# How to cancel gcc alias with Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, gcc, terminal, xcode5, alias

Since I have updated to Xcode5, gcc in terminal is aliased as clang. Now I have installed gcc 4.8 through HomeBrew, how can I use gcc in terminal, that is, how to cancel the alias of gcc to clang?
If I type

```
gcc --version
```

I will get

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

So how can I use gcc in terminal? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

What does your `$PATH` look like? Look inside ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile or wherever you set `PATH`

You should move `/usr/local/bin` in front of `/usr/bin`

This is a PATH where the "home brew directory" has precedence over the system directories:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Your $PATH should look similar. Your shell should look into `/usr/local/bin` first, this is the install directory for homebrew tools. Only if the command can't be found there your shell should search the system provided directories like `/usr/bin/`

---

Or: run `brew doctor`. It might tell you what to do exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it still doesn't work. 
Even if I use the same $PATH as you mentioned above, I still got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Trying doing `hash -r` to reset Bash cached paths after changing your path so that `usr/local/`bin is in front of `/usr/bin`